# How do I move a list into a word document in r?

Tags: r

Please can you advise me on how to move a list generated in K into a Word document that I can edit etc.

An example of the list is below, which I have cut and paste.  But I would like to make it more professional and add and take away columns etc.

Many thanks in advance

```
[[1]]
[[1]]summary
 Absolute.Neg.100 Absolute.Pos.100
 Min.   : 3.823   Min.   : 5.807  
 1st Qu.: 5.666   1st Qu.: 5.907  
 Median : 6.846   Median : 6.960  
 Mean   : 7.491   Mean   : 7.913  
 3rd Qu.: 8.380   3rd Qu.: 8.966  
 Max.   :20.874   Max.   :11.925  
 NA's   :12       NA's   :76      

[[1]]Wilcox. Test

Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
```

`data:  data[, 1]` and `data[, 2]`
`W = 117`, `p-value = 0.6493`
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to `0`

Comment: http://galahad.well.ox.ac.uk/repro/

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use R Markdown to write the output to Microsoft Word, along with the `knitr::kable()` function to print as a table.

For example:

````
---
title: "Sample output"
author: "Len Greski"
date: "July 26, 2018"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document illustrating an answer to Stackoverflow question about printing output in a nice format in Microsoft Word, [51537478](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51537478/how-do-i-move-a-list-into-a-word-document-in-r). The `knitr::kable()` function can be used to generate tables in an R Markdown document, which can be used to write output to Microsoft Word. 

We'll use the sample `cars` data set and print the output of the `summary()` function with `knitr::kable()`. 

```{r cars}
library(knitr)
kable(summary(cars))
```
````

creates the following Microsoft Word document:

[image]

Comment: Hello Liesl. If the answer worked, please accept it.